# Widgets overflows when soft keyboard opens

Tags: flutter

I am using TabBarView with tabs in flutter. My tab bar view contains input form. Now when the keyboard opens the widgets overflows

I tried using Listview and SingleChildScrollView to avoid this issue but its not working for me. When using ListView or SingleChildScrollView the screen goes blank.

`@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 0,
                child: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Sign In'),
                    Tab(text: 'Sign Up'),
                  ],
                  labelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: TabBarView(
                    children: [_buildSignInForm(), _buildSignupForm()]),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }`

Comment: is there any error or exception in the log ?

Comment: EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY 
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
 When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
 flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
 space in the vertical direction.

Comment: Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
 themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
 then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
 constraints provided by the parent.

Comment: I tried the solution suggested but that didn't work for me as well.

Comment: consider defining a `height` property to the `Column` widget

Comment: we cannot give height to a column

Comment: sorry, I meant `Container`, wrap your `Column` in it and set the height to match the screen height by : `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,`

Comment: yes that worked for me. Thanks

Comment: kindly accept the answer

Comment: Although when the soft keyboard opens it doesn't automatically scroll upwards to show the current field.

Comment: it won't you just have to place textfields on the top of your page, it is an elementary design principle

Comment: okay thanks, made that adjustment. You can post your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` inside a `Container` widget and set the height to match the screen height by :

```
`height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,`
```